Use concepts to check inheritance from templated class with only partially known template parameters
For the following type system,
template <typename U, typename V>
struct Base { ... };

struct Derived1 : Base<TypeA, TypeB> { ... };
struct Derived2 : Base<TypeA, TypeC> { ... };

I would like to be able to write functions that accept parameters that have been derived from Base while restricting some (none, all) the first N of the template parameters in Base (where N might be zero). My idea is to use C++ concepts for this (though I'm open for other approaches!). Essentially, I am looking for something like
template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
concept FromBase = requires ...

such that I can write functions like this
void foo(FromBase auto param);               // accepts anything derived from `Base`
void foo(FromBase<TypeA> auto param);        // accepts `Derived1` and `Derived2`
void foo(FromBase<TypeA, TypeB> auto param); // accepts `Derived1`, but not `Derived2`

That is, the resulting concept should enable overload resolution such that having more matching template arguments results in a higher specificity?
How would I do this with concepts? Or is this even possible with C++? Note that I'm specifically looking for a solution that is "easy on the eyes and mind", i.e., ideally I don't want to use N different concepts to support N potential parameters.
Bonus question: Is this also possible with mixed type/non-type template parameters in Base?
EDIT: Clarified that the concepts should take part in overload resolution, from more generic to more specific.

"some (none, all) of the template parameters" that's 2^N of these combinations, do you really want all of them?

@n.m.couldbeanAI sorry, I was not clear before and adapted it accordingly on the question: I want to restrict the first N parameters. It should not be an arbitrary combination.

You can define such a concept by checking the validity of lambda expressions:
template <typename Derived, typename... SpecifiedArgs>
concept FromBase = requires (const Derived& d) {
  requires (requires { [](const Base<SpecifiedArgs...>&){}(d); } ||
            requires { []<typename... Ts>(const Base<SpecifiedArgs..., Ts...>&){}(d); });
};

Demo

Thanks, that exactly satisfies my original question. However, I failed to properly highlight that the concept should be able to take part in overload resolution (more matching template args = higher specificity). Is it possible to modify your solution to allow that as well?

If this is too much to ask in a single question, I can also revert my question to the original one and create a new question.
Side question: Does your solution also allow to mix non-type and regular template parameters?

@MichaelSchlottke-Lakemper It should already support any number of specified types.

Hm, I don't think so, at least in CE I get errors about ambiguous function calls: https://godbolt.org/z/4TsdY599M

As a follow up, @康桓瑋, why is the first requires clause with const Base<SpecifiedArgs...>& necessary? Wouldn't const Base<SpecifiedArgs..., Ts...>&already cover this withTs...` expanding to a null set if it's empty?

@MichaelSchlottke-Lakemper The current standard wording does not allow Ts... to be an empty pack.

Thanks! Do you also have an idea on how to rewrite the concept (maybe recursively) such that more matching template parameters have a higher specificity and thus partake in overload resolution? right now, changing bar and baz to foo will not work due to ambiguity.

According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack, "A template parameter pack is a template parameter that accepts zero or more template arguments". So it does seem like Ts... maybe an empty pack, or am I missing something?

@MichaelSchlottke-Lakemper I mean in that context not general cases.
